# Coinbase Redirect and Callback URLs Setup

Tags: paypal, callback, bitcoin, coinbase-api

I'm trying to get a website to accept bitcoins. Right now it uses ZenCart and Paypal to receive payments. I followed all the steps to install Coinbase's ZenCart Plugin. It's all setup on Zencart but now I need to give Coinbase 3 redirect URLs. It wants a Success, Cancel, and Info URL but I don't know what the URLs should be. I also don't know what to put for the callback URL... Any help would be appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The 3 urls (success, cancel, and info) are for what the user does. If the user pays the correct amount, what page should he be forwarded too? Usually its a page saying "Thank you for your purchase". If someone cancels the order in the middle, they should be forwarded to a different page. Finally the info page should contain some information on the transaction. Im not sure what to put for the callback as I dont even see it as an option in the installation process. Feel free to read the README.md file in the plugin. https://github.com/coinbase/coinbase-zencart

Comment: I did read the readme.md but it wasn't very helpful with this.

Comment: Could you provide some pictures of the fields that you still need to fill out?